# lastfm json response 'undefined'

Tags: jquery, json, last.fm

I just started messing around with the lastfm API and I'm not sure why the response from chart.getlovedtracks is coming back undefined, using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var apiKey = "myapikey";
$.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.getlovedtracks&api_key='+     apiKey +'&format=json&callback=?', 
function(data) {
console.log('Fetched ' + data.length + ' items!');
});
});
```

Am I missing something, seems pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be including the `callback` parameter unless you intend to use a callback function.

You were also not parsing the JSON as expected. You can get the number of tracks returned with `data.tracks.track.length`.

This code works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
    $.getJSON('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.getlovedtracks&api_key=' + apiKey + '&format=json', function(data) {
        console.log('Fetched ' + data.tracks.track.length + ' items!');
    });
});
```